# Extension by a skyscraper sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $C$ be a nodal curve. Then we have the normalisation map $f: \mathbb{P}^1 \to C$. I want to understand the sheaf $f_* \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$. There is the map $\mathcal{O}_{C} \to f_* \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$ and it is injective since $f$ is surjective. Moreover, the quotient is supported at the singular point since $f$ is an isomorphism on the smooth locus of $C$. Thus, we have the sequence $0 \to \mathcal{O}_{C} \to f_* \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \to i_* k \to 0$ where $i: x \to C$ for the singular point $x \in C$. Does this sequence split? It amounts to compute $ \text{Ext}^1 (i_* k, \mathcal{O}_{C}) $ but I'm not sure how to compute it since $x$ is not a regular point and we cannot use the Koszul resolution.

Comment: Have you tried computing affine-locally? Taking an affine neighborhood of the node makes this an algebra problem where you should be able to make some progress. (Minor nitpick: when you say "let $C$ be a nodal curve", you may want to specify *which one* - it seems likely that you're talking about the nodal cubic, but there are lots of different nodal curves out there.)

Comment: @KReiser Yes, you're right, I've meant the nodal cubic here. Locally, we want to resolve A=k[t]/(t^2-1, t^3-t) by free k[t]-modules. It seems we can do 0 \to k[x] \to k[x] + k[x] \to k[x] \to A where the left map takes q to (qt, 0) and the next map takes (a, b) to a(t^2-1)+b(t^3-t). I'll try to do this carefully but what if this Ext group is nonzero? In this case it won't tell that it doesn't split, it only will tell that it might be non-split (but also might be split).

Comment: There are more ways to tell whether you've got a split extension than computing the element in ext corresponding to your exact sequence! You can look at the exact sequence and reason through whether what you have is split or not without necessarily invoking ext.

Comment: @KReiser Hm.. It seems that when we're working affine-locally it splits since we just need to find a map k[t]/(t^2-1, t^3-t) -> k[t] and we can take t -> 1. However, it doesn't imply that it splits globally.

Comment: If $f \colon X \to Y$ is a dominant morphism then $F$ is a torsion free sheaf on $X$ then $f_*F$ is a torsion free sheaf on $Y$. This proves that the sequence does not split.

Comment: @Sasha oh, I'm an idiot; that makes a lot of sense!